# How to add different classes to template element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, backbone.js

In my JSON file I have 7 objects, where first 3 of them have `"is_read" attribute == 1,` and last 4 have `"is_read" == 0`.
I add rows, using a template and want to give **tr** different classes according to their `"is_read"` value (`".news_read"` for `"is_read" == 1` and `".news_unread"` for `"is_read" == 0`).

However, I end up with 7 rows that all have "news_unread" class. Though, console.log shows that I have 3 `"newsData.get('is_read') == 1"` and 4 `"newsData.get('is_read') == 0"` objects.

I wonder how to create rows with different classes. I tried to do newsRow.addClass, but the error message says that an object `<tr><td>...</td></tr>` (newsRow template) can't have a method addClass.

```
render: function() {
    news.fetchMyNews();
    for (var i = 1; i <= news.length; i++)   {
        var newsData = news.get(i);
        var newsRow = JST["news/row"](newsData.attributes);
        $("#news_tbody").append(newsRow).first('tr').attr("class",function(){
            if (newsData.get('is_read') == 1)
                return "news_read";
            else if (newsData.get('is_read') == 0)
                return "news_unread";
        });
    }           
}
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> I tried to do newsRow.addClass, but the error message says that an object ... (newsRow template) can't have a method addClass.

But I can't find `addClass` in your example code:

```
$("#news_tbody").append(newsRow).first('tr').attr("class",function(){
    if (newsData.get('is_read') == 1)
        return "news_read";
    else if (newsData.get('is_read') == 0)
        return "news_unread";
 });
```

I just can advice you to try this code(use `addClass`, instead of `attr` and add blocks in if statement):

```
$("#news_tbody").append(newsRow).first('tr').addClass(function(){
    if (newsData.get('is_read') === 1){
        return "news_read";
    } else if (newsData.get('is_read') === 0) {
        return "news_unread";
    }
});
```

Comment: Now tbody has both classes: "news_read" and "news_unread".
<tbody id="news_tbody" class="news_read news_unread">

Answer (score 0):

As @Pinal suggested, I used addClass instead.

However, after `append(newsRow)` I used `.children('tr')` and it worked fine.

```
$("#news_tbody").append(newsRow).children('tr').addClass(function(){
  if (newsData.get('is_read') === 1){
    return "news_read";
  } else if (newsData.get('is_read') === 0) {
    return "news_unread";
  }
});
```